# Gradle is issuing an error "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to create a simple android project with gradle. I work in a computer with Debian GNU/Linux 7 'wheezy'.

I followed the recomendations in [Gradle Plugin User Guide - Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Differences-between-a-Project-and-a-Library-Project), but it casts an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/alex/Proyectos/MyLogin/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyLogin'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.817 secs
```

I followed the specifications:

- Gradle 1.9
- Plugin 0.7
- SDK    17+ (actually 19)

I also started a project anew, and the results I showed were issued by the command `gradle tasks` as shown in the documentation.

I also tried gradle 1.10, but the result is the same.

Even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649668/gradle-errors-in-android-studio) was not usefull, since it solved with 'upgrading' to gradle 1.6 (I understand that plugin 0.7 requires at least gradle 1.9).

I tried this after failing with the same error in **android-studio** and **IntelliJ Idea**.

**EDIT:** I also tried with new projects in both IDEs, and got the same issue. But what most surprises me is that both IDEs use gradle 1.8 in their wrapped form. I tried to cinfigure both of them to use my local gradle install, but still the same issue.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug? How can I avoid the problem?

Please, help me.

**EDIT:** Here is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.6

version = '0.1'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    //compile project(':core')
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your "build.gradle" looks like?

Comment: Sorry for the ommition of such important data. Here is the `build.gradle`.

Comment: I tried this "build.gradle" - the bug appears under gradle 1.10 and solved by downgrading to 1.9.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google made a mistake with version 0.7.2 of the [Gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system):

> Note: 0.7.2 requires Java7. This is a mistake. Use 0.7.3 instead.

Release 0.7.3 re-enables Java6 support. Declaring Gradle 0.7.3 in my build files does indeed resolve this for me.

No one is perfect :)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was fixed with the release of 0.7.3. I have it configurated with "0.7.+".

Comment: Glad it is fixed for you. I've stopped using the expression "0.7.+" because 0.6, 0.7.1 and 0.7.2 caused me problems. I now fix on a release - e.g. "0.7.3".

Answer (score 22):

Use Gradle 1.9 instead of Gradle 1.10.  There is an issue with 1.10 : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63822

Also answered here:

[Can't find org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult when apply Android plugin in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812703/cant-find-org-gradle-api-artifacts-result-resolvedmoduleversionresult-when-appl)

Comment: Should have read more carefully, I see you already tried 1.9.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. This answer should be 'accepted'

Comment: OK. It solves the problem. It seems that I had missplaced the version in my PATH environment variable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, for future reference, switching to a newer version of gradle would/should also fix this.

Answer (score 19):

I got it working using Gradle 1.10 with the Gradle plugin 0.8.0.

```
// /build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration 
// options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

...

```
# /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.
#Sat Feb 01 20:41:29 CET 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put gradle:0.8.+ instead of gradle:0.8.0?  That way you know you're using the latest gradle plugin.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsy Not necessarily best. For instance, if at the time you had done gradle:0.7.+ you might well have hit problems that are now well-known. The latest is not always the greatest.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the command line to create the project like so:

```
android create project -g -v 1.2.2 --target 1 --name rtest --path rtest --activity MainActivity --package com.mydomain.rtest
```

The project is created to use version 1.2.2 of the android-gradle-plugin, but the project is initialised with gradle 1.12, which [isn't compatible](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility).

To fix it, do the following:

1. Open `rtest/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and set `distributionUrl` to the release you want; for example: `http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` (don't forget to escape the colon - yes, that makes me smile too);
2. Open `build.gradle` and change `runProguard false` to `minifyEnabled false`;
3. `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug`
4. I also remove the hidden `.gradle` folder, but I'm not sure if it's necessary

And it all works again.

Comment: thanks! this is the solution that works for me with the latest set of tools. (as of July 2015)

Comment: Thanks! Google is so shamelessly drinking the Kool-aid from Idea, their command line tools are in a sorry state...

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using 2.1 version of studio, replace classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-rc1' with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to update your Gradle 1.9 project to Gradle 1.10 using

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

and command `./gradlew wrapper` you will get the same error as above.

Solution is to install Gradle 1.10 onto your machine and upgrade your project **not using the wrapper**

`gradle wrapper`

Comment: Is there any way to download gradle wrapper 1.10 and put that into Android Studio?

Comment: you have to do it in a file explorer and avoid ASide

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you update your system gradle and forget to update the Android Studio gradle home.

Answer (score 0):

I got this today when running gradle assembleRelease. I had installed the Ubuntu default of gradle-1.4. This didn't work, so I tried the latest gradle-1.12 and got the same issue.

Downloading and using gradle-1.10 (and matching my gradle-wrapper.properties file to that version) resolved the issue.

This is with Android Studio 0.5.8.

Comment: Any explanation of the -1? I was sharing a working solution at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i guess android studio has answer for this to get this bug out using GUI,

I had this error like this...
[image]

after updating the plugins i was facing another issues while building,

[image]

so changes the `gradle setting` to default as shown in the image,
[image]

After this build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to dependencies and just change the dependencies classpath to
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
Rest Gradle will take care. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1: Run with scan to see detailed cause.
2: In my case it was pointing to a file in cache(c/user/.gradle/cache/jr-9...).
3: I deleted jr-9 folder and it fixed my issue