# Can't find org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult when apply Android plugin in Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

When I upgrade gradle to 1.10 in my Ubuntu 12.04, I can't build android gradle project, tell  me Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin', debug message is like:

```
15:35:52.069 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/ResolvedModuleVersionResult
15:35:52.073 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.$getStaticMetaClass(AppPlugin.groovy)
15:35:52.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:1627)
15:35:52.101 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:73)
15:35:52.105 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
15:35:52.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
15:35:52.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 43 more
15:35:52.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult
15:35:52.157 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 48 more
```

Anybody can tell me how to fix this? or jsut Gradle 1.10 have some problems?

Comment: same problem with MacOsX, gradle 1.10, intelli IDEA 13

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found there is an issue in Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker [Issue #63822](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63822): Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult'

reply by #1 ibill...@pivotallabs.com

> It would seem Gradle 1.10 is not supported.  Try using an older version of Gralde.
>
> Notice that ResolvedModuleVersionResult is missing here
>
> http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.10/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/package-summary.html
>
> but is present here
>
> http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.9/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/package-summary.html

So I downgrade my gradle to 1.9, it works again.

**[Edit My Answer Here For How To Downgrade Gradle in Mac and Ubuntu]**

For Mac: I use Homebrew, try [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula), I use 3.a historic times, works great for me.

For Ubuntu: If you already installed 1.10, try this:

```sh
# Install both gradle 1.9 and 1.10 on you ubuntu
sudo apt-get install gradle-1.9

# Check it to make sure
sudo update-alternatives --list gradle

# Config to choose gradle 1.9
sudo update-alternatives --config gradle
# Just select /usr/lib/gradle/1.9/bin/gradle to choose gradle 1.9
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - No alternatives. Running Gradle 1.4. Anyone know a good repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to update your Gradle 1.9 (or lower) project to Gradle 1.10 using

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

and command `./gradlew wrapper` you will get the same error as above.

Solution is to install Gradle 1.10 onto your machine and upgrade your project **not using the wrapper**

`gradle wrapper`