# Expected ResolvedDependencyResult but found DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult when trying to sync

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.6.1

I am using Android Studio 3.6.1 and Gradle `6.3-all`. I tried to sync my project and got the following error:

> Expected org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult but
>   found
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult

No idea how to fix this.

Comment: File>invalidate caches/restart

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin thanks replying, already tried that multiple times, without luck. Keep getting the same error.

Comment: See my answer for this question and change your dependencies, then sync. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960

Comment: Do I need to update the dependencies individually as well?

Comment: Update it, it should work

Comment: I updated all dependencies and did: File>invalidate caches/restart, but still the error occurs.

Comment: Don't update dependencies, copy and paste my dependencies to see it works or not

Comment: I copied and pasted your dependencies, and resycned, but no change

Comment: Again previous error?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilded the project?!

Comment: If I try to run: Clean Project, it gives me the same error: Expected org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult but found org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812703/cant-find-org-gradle-api-artifacts-result-resolvedmoduleversionresult-when-appl

Comment: Why would I downgrade to 1.9? That is really old. I also tried downgrading to an slightly older version (4.3), but the same error still shows.

Comment: Try View > Tool Windows > Gradle

Comment: I also added it to the gradle github: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12723 and it seems more people have the same issue. So I wonder if this a general issue.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin tried that, but nothing shown there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Some how I got working, by running the following command: watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache, also removed the .gradle & .idea folders and some .iml files and reopend the project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android Studio 3.6.2, 3.6.1 version has bug

Comment: Thanks for the reply, already tried updating, but the error remains, also tried resetting the whole thing, it's frustrating.

Comment: Ok, Some how I got working, by running the following command: watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache, also removed the .gradle & .idea folders and some .iml files and reopend the project.

Comment: I suspect that there is a gradle cache inside node_modules, removing the directory fixes the issue.

Comment: clearing out node_modules did the trick!  You're a life saver @udarts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while creating APK. The following steps help me to resolve the issue.

1. Change the Gradle version to 6.1.1.
2. Delete node module and npm install.
3. npm cache verify.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on flutter and resolved by upgrade gralde version

build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
```

gradle-warpper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
```