# Gradle: Could not create plugin of type AppPlugin

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can't seem to build my Android app with Gradle.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode = 82
        versionName = "0.6.1"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        xposedmodule {
            manifest.srcFile 'xposed/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['xposed/src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['xposed/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['xposed/src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['xposed/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['xposed/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['xposed/assets']
        }

    }

    /*
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }*/

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

// ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
if (project.hasProperty('keystoreFile') &&
        project.hasProperty('keystorePassword') &&
        project.hasProperty('keystoreAliasPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(keystoreFile)
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = keystorePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keystoreAliasPassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keystoreAlias
} else {
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

I use Gradle 1.10 and I get the following error when issuing this command:

```
gradle build.gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

Error:

```
Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle is issuing an error "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooops, appearently I was using the wrong version of Gradle. My bad!

This 2 [lines](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle) could make it clear what version is used

```
println GradleVersion.current().prettyPrint()
assert gradle.gradleVersion >= "1.10" // android plugin 0.10 requires Gradle 1.10, 1.11, 1.12
```

Comment: so what was the right version of Gradle and were their any steps specific to your project to use unsaid version?

Comment: The correct version was 1.6, and I dont think there were.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, run `cmd.exe` as Administrator and input `gradle` command in the cmd console, the error is gone.