# spoon gradle : Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'

Tags: java, android, gradle, spoon

my gradle project was build succeed, but when add spoon ,then i got this error (Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin')

my gradle version 1.9

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'spoon'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3.1'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.0.5'
}
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace (running gradle in debug mode)?

Comment: Try to use different version of this plugin

Comment: @IWillTryToCodeIt thank you, i retry some times, but still get this error

Comment: See the answer by JJD at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin

Answer (score 0):

The minimum supported version Android plugin is 0.8. However there is no good documentation against what Spoon plugin version should be used with what version of Android plugin at the moment.
I recommend using the latest versions of both plugins, which will also require newer Gradle version.

P.S.
There was a github issue raised by you: https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin/issues/14. Right? :)