# error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle 1.0.0 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have just update my android studio from 1.1.0 to 1.2.2.but it is showing the error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle1.0.0 available for offline mode.when I do it for online then again the error isError:Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.0/gradle-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
I am importing the project from desktop.

Comment: check out this link:
[Gradle is issuing an error “Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin)