# Android error on running the app

Tags: android, plugins

I get the following error while I am trying to run the app.I have earlier updated the Android Studio.Gradle has also been posted below.
Error:

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jobinsabu.georgetravels"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'

}
```

Comment: please check now gradle has been posted

Comment: upgrade gradle version

Comment: I added classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0' to the dependency.I get the following error:                                                 Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "c9940005c89536c6e958c4c73fd34f3fdcb919e0"
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:\GeorgeTravels\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Try updating the sdk extras and buildtoolversions and your build.gradle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811514/gradle-is-issuing-an-error-could-not-create-plugin-of-type-appplugin

Answer (score 2):

Check your grade file and update classpath version here:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

}
}
```

Try to change your classpath version and then update.
Make sure you are connected to internet for gradle syncing.

Hope it may helpful to you.

Thanks,

Bhuvnesh