# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to update gradle from 1.3.1 to 3.5, as some of my dependencies requires version 3.3 or above.

I've seen similar questions, but none of them help.

**build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5'
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

Still i'm getting this when trying to do anything (build, clean etc):

```
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'chat'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5/gradle-3.5.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5/gradle-3.5.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 57):

#### To fix this issue check do you have **google()** repo in your **project's level build.gradle** file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //HAVE YOU MISS IT?
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //HAVE YOU MISS IT?
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to remove this from repositories: mavenCentral()

Comment: if you are updating from a very old version of maven (below 4), `google()` alias is not yet included, use `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` instead

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between the Android Plugin for Gradle version and the Gradle version being used. The plugin version typically matches the version number of Android Studio you are using. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) for more information. So if using the latest stable Android Studio it should currently be `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1`.

These values can also be reviewed and set from the Project Structure window in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: and if i don't use android studio? because i don't

Comment: @stkvtflw, Well, just replace `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5'` with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`

Comment: As Egor has mentioned as long as you update the project build.gradle file to reference an Android Plugin for Gradle version that actually exists and is compatible with the Gradle version as shown in the link I gave it should work. I just showed the Project Structure window as an alternative since it seemed like you knew how to update the value from the build.gradle file.

Comment: 2019: I got this error when trying to import an old Eclipse ADT project into Android Studio. The Android Plugin Version was 3.5, so I changed the Gradle version to 5.4.1 based on something in the docs (note that their order in Project Structure has been swapped). Then I had to click "Add Google Maven repository and resync" or something like that before the error went away.

Comment: Android studio is the worst IDE I used in my lift. Every time there will be tons of compatibility issues when there is a new version.

Answer (score 2):

***Try this***

```
  ** If you are using android studio 3.5 and your build.gradle(Project 
level) is=> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1' or => 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'.
than replace with *** 

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' to 

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' 

                   OR 
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had `google()` repo both in `buildscript` and `allprojects` repositories, but still it shows me `Could not find gradle-3.5.3` error
Finally I added `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`, and it fixed the errors!

project's level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }  // <= this line
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }  // <= this line
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to save your build.gradle (for whatever reason, Android Studio doesn't always save your latest changes, as I found even with Android Studio 3.5.3, the gradle sync kept failing even after I had changed the classpath line, and it only picked up the new value after saving the build.gradle file)

Answer (score 0):

I got an error after changing version code from 2 to 2.1. 
When I opened the build with ctrl+shift+alt+s, I realized adding .1 (decimals) resulted in a $ symbol being added to the right and so build failed. I opted to use numbers without decimal positions and it worked. 
For example, I used 3 for buildversion because I wanted to upgrade the app in playstore.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25743599)

Comment: Suraj Kumar, I was just giving my fix not a question. Zubair, thank you for the edit, My English is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case turning on Charles helped. Android Studio just could not download required resources when Charles was turned off.