# android studio gradle problem : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, mobile

I installed android studio 3.5 and gradle 5.4.1 installed automatically and successfully, but after that sync fails and a problem appears every time :

((( ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
  Required by:
  project :
  Open File )))

and my build.gradle file is like this :
[build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6evG2.png)

Noting that I tried many android studio versions and same problem appears.

Any solutions please ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648844/8872691) worked for me sometime back.

Comment: Yes I already have google() repo in my build.gradle file and the problem is still appear.

Answer (score 0):

This normally rises when your internet connection is unstable when studio is downloading gradle I would suggest:

- uninstall studio and its config files in `appdata` dir files (dont delete Androidstuidoprojects)
- restart your pc
- install studio when you are sure you have a stable connection

NB: once gradle download fails midway you have to manually delete it in C:/Users/pc-name/gradle so make sure it works the first time