# Android Studio 3.1.3 and Gradle 4.4 - Failed to resolve com

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've cloned a repository into my computer using Android Studio 3.1.3, this project used Gradle 4.1 so the IDE prompted to update it to 4.4 as the minimum version supported for this (at least following the IDE message) is 4.4.

When I update the distributionUrl gradle version from 4.1 to 4.4 it now says this:

```
Failed to resolve: com
```

and when I press in 'Open File' it indicates the error is in this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I already made the google() repository go before jcenter() and still the error persists. Did google changed how to use the android plugin in gradle?

Comment: I think you need android studio 3.2 to use gradle 4.4 check at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application

Comment: I found the error, it was Facebook Stetho. for some reason it has some issues with Gradle 4.4