# Unable to install cordova-plugin-camera in ionic 1 framework Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-camera

I have try to install the cordova-plugin-camera plugin in the existing ionic 1 framework project but it always displayed the error while installing through the command prompt.

When i have create the new ionic 1 project it getting installed without any error

Please suggest on this
[image]

After updating the gradle 5.1.1 in android studio i am facing the below issue please refer the screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqceR.png)

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

ionic framework 1
cordova 7.1.0

Comment: Whats your gradle version?

Comment: i have used gradle-3.3 in the android studio

Comment: Can you update your gradle version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application

Comment: Yes just now i have update the gradle version to 5.1.1 but facing same issue

Comment: Is it possible to migrate your ionic 1 app to ionic 4?

Comment: What is your Ionic Version??? and Remove platform, install Plugin first and add platform after plugin installation.

Comment: @Fearcoder - possible but it takes time

Comment: @Najam us Saqib - i have created the neew project and then install plugin then build the platform that time i am unable to build the project too :(

Comment: Not sure but maybe it's deprecated?