# Build file 'D:\AndroidStudio\clone_flutter\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

While connect my app with firebase  generate SHA key app-level build.gradel shows an error in line 24 after adding google.json file I don't get where I am doing wrong line 24 starts from apply plugin. I upgrade flutter still I am getting this error -

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "mdhv.co.clone_flutter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After run Flutter doctor don't get any issue then where is the problem?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.3-pre.54, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: [Android Studio failed to apply plugin id com.android.application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application) would this help at all?

Comment: No man. I am getting this error after setup plugin of firebase

Answer (score 0):

The error you've provided is complete, but build errors are usually caused by the added package not being installed correctly. Running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` should do the job. Also, depending on the Firebase products that you're using, you only need to use Firebase CLI and flutterfire_cli to [setup Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) in your Flutter project.