# How do I add AWS Amplify into my android application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, plugins, aws-amplify

I am following the AWS docs, [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1). I am able to add everything into my project's `build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, and app's `build.gradle` EXCEPT for the apply plugin. When I add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.amazonaws.appsync']
```

How do I fix this? When I remove the apply plugin from the app's `build.gradle`, then my app works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try updating you gradle version and is your android studio also in the latest state, follow this thread and also update your question with the project's build.gradle file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091489/1503130

Comment: Thanks. I actually had to lower my gradle version because I was initially on the newest gradle. After lowering it, it worked. Appreciate it!

Comment: @TonyLiu Is this still an issue with 1.0.1 of the plugin? Do you still need to lower your Gradle version? If so, to what version, from what version?

Comment: @Jameson Thanks for making my question look more presentable. I downgraded from Gradle 6 to Gradle 5.6.4 for it to work. I still have it on 5.6.4 to prevent any more bugs at the moment.