# i get this error when i run my flutter code with dart in visual studio code its says to upgrade sdk

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'H:\lion_express_courier_driver_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in H:\lion_express_courier_driver_app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Failed to apply plugin \[id 'com.android.application'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your `gradle` version above 6.5. I think version 7 will be fine. Go to `build.gradle` file and change your `gradle` version.

Open `Project > android > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties`

Replace this - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

With - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.0-all.zip`