# Android Studio - Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: android, gradle

I have made an android studio project and then there was a prompt to upgrade my gradle version. I did so and then it did some downloads and it got updated. After that, I cleaned the project and then I received this error: - . I am also receciving some errors like "Failed to evaluate values files".

\app\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> The option 'android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing' is deprecated.
> The current default is 'false'.
> It was removed in version 4.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> This feature was removed in AGP 4.0

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config/checkstyle.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hardik.document_scanner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://repository.aspose.com/repo/" }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

    // persistence room library - for db operations
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'

    // material ripple, morphing button, material dialog, animations
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk:android-morphing-button:98a4986e56'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'

    // libraries for reading from doc and docx files
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '2.4.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-scratchpad', version: '3.9'

    // Itext hardik library
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'

    // Picasso, image editor, image cropper
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'ja.burhanrashid52:photoeditor:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

    // Viewpager transformation
    implementation 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'

    // Image picker, and folder picker
    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.5.3-beta3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'lib.kashif:folderpicker:2.4'
    // Zxing - for scanning qr code
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    // color picker
    implementation 'com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar'

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0'
}
preBuild.dependsOn('checkstyle')
assemble.dependsOn('lint')
check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
```

the module level gradle file:-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }

        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the checkstyle.gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

dependencies {
    checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:7.6.1'
}

def qualityConfigDir = "$project.rootDir/config/"
def reportsDir = "$project.buildDir/reports"

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle, group: 'Verification', description: 'Runs code style checks') {
    configFile file("$qualityConfigDir/checkstyle_config.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination file("$reportsDir/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
        }
    }

    classpath = files( )
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show this module's gradle file, ../config/checkstyle.gradle. This file should be under Project folder of your app.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal Updated both the files

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application?rq=1)?

Comment: @PrachiChouksey No not this, I need this gradle file /config/checkstyle.gradle.. This should be under Project folder/config/checkstyle.gradle.

Comment: I have updated the files