# Gradle failure A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' and Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build the gradle for my app but the build fails

I've looked around some other questions regarding to this issue and I couldn't solve it. Also, I have tried changing the gradle build tool version, adding different lib and some more stuff which didn't mange to solve the problem.

```
   buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Write the exact error shown in console here.

Comment: may this link help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application